# Can you enable Remote Desktop Connection on a new first-turned-on Windows PC via a CD/USB stick WITHOUT a monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control

I have a specific problem. I'm trying to get a relative to setup a new PC for me. The issue is there is no monitor installed!

When it arrives I want a relative to plug it in (just the basics, power and [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)) and then for me to be able to remote administer it via the local home network. I'm at another location, but I could access the home network via the router without any problem.

I have no idea if this is possible. It would be a new Windows 7/8 PC, so it would have some intro message/configuration screens to get past in theory and maybe they need to type in the Windows key?

All I need is to be able to enable remote desktop on the thing. As my relative will have physical access to it, I wondered if there is some way in which I could get my relative to insert a USB stick/CD and run some process to enable [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) automatically?

Comment: Do you have access to the computer before it is shipped to the relative so you can do some pre-setup work on it or will it be coming from the supplier of the computer directly and you will not be able to do any prep work on it before it is given to your relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you need to install Windows 7 / 8 with a monitor right? I cannot see how you would otherwise actually remote to this physical machine without RDP activated. In a virtual machine environment it is possible to do so through the console screen, although it is not the same as RDP.

So say you have a monitor just for the installation of the OS, you might as well configure RDP after the installation. A password is necessary for security reasons, so you must configure one during or after the installation of Windows. Then, you need to allow remote access to that computer. A quick was is to go to start > type "allow remote" without quotes and select `Allow remote access to your computer`
[image]

Now select `Allow remote connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication` and proceed to select `Select Users` and select your default user.
[image]

You can disconnect the monitor now and no USB flash or anything is neccessary to keep your RDP started. You just have to keep the physical machine powered on. The IP must also be static from your router, to prevent IP confusion.

Comment: So if you can ask one of your relatives to offer their monitor for 40mins to setup this, Im sure it's save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Hi @Rudolph

There is no monitor im afraid, and windows would be pre-installed most likely, hence the bit about the first time powered on I wrote.

Comment: @AdamJones - Given that no monitor is available.. you might need to contact the supplier or assembler of this workstation and ask to configure it for you completely, as Windows is gonna ask for the first startup details. This is not possible through a terminal as far as I know.  So best would be probably to ask the supplier to load teamviewer  and configure it to startup automatically, obviously giving the ID and manual teamviewer-password as well. Apart from the suggestion, a script is probably needed from flash and then you should migrate the question to StackOverflow